# Python get latest files list and compare it with old files list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, filesystems

**GOAL**

get the latest files list from target dir every 30 min

**My Solution** (if you know better please let me know)

1. Get a list of files every 30 min from the target dir.
2. compare current Files with the new Files list
3. make a new list of the latest files.

**Problem**

1. Get a list of files every 30 min from the target dir.

Here I don't know how to get a list of current and after 30 min?

here Function return list.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join


    def getFileNames(mypath):
        onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
        return onlyfiles
```

Comment: if you use Linux then you could use `cron` to run code every 30 minutes - but you would have to keep list in file - read it at start and save it at the end of script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can check for new files every 30 minutes in Python:

```py
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from time import sleep


def getFileNames(mypath):
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
    return onlyfiles

folder = "/tmp" #location of temp files on Linux
old = getFileNames(folder)
while True:
    sleep(1800) #30 minutes
    new = getFileNames(folder)
    newFiles = [f for f in new if f not in old]
    print(newFiles)
    old = new
```